# Bulk operations NgRX to import a huge list of data

Tags: angular, ngrx

actually i try to build an import feature into my angular 6 application based one NgRx. 
The source is a CSV-List with about 7.000-10.000 rows which should be imported into my mongo db. The huge amount of data is too large to dispatch this in a single action so I've tried to send a action for each row. 
Here is the Effect for this action.

```
  /**
   * Adds a single transactions, if it ot already exist.
   * 
   * @dispatches: ActionOutbankImportSuccess() if the transactions exists or was created
   *              ActionOutbankImportError() if an error  occoured
   */
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  addOutbankCSVRow = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ActionOutbankImportAdd>(OutbankImportActionTypes.ADD),
    tap((action) =>
      //  fetch transactions with the given values to  avoid duplicates 
      this.transactionsService
        .transactions({
          name: action.payload.transaction.name.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ''),
          reason: action.payload.transaction.reason.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ''),
          amount: action.payload.transaction.amount,
          date: action.payload.transaction.date,
        })
        .pipe(
          tap(next => console.log(next)),
          tap((existing) => {
            //  if there are no equal transactions ...
            if (existing.length > 0) {
              this.store.dispatch(new ActionOutbankImportSuccess())
            } else {
              //  ... create one 
              this.transactionsService
                .createTransaction(action.payload.transaction)
                .pipe(
                  map(() => this.store.dispatch(new ActionOutbankImportSuccess())),
                  catchError(error => {
                    this.store.dispatch(new ActionOutbankImportError({ error: error }));
                    return of();
                  })
                )
            }
          })
        )
    )
  );
```

Here is the actual method which starts the import:

```
this.outbankCSVParserService
    .parseCSVFile(files[0])
    .subscribe(rows => {
      this.store.dispatch(
        new ActionOutbankImportStart({ totalCount: rows.length })
      );

      rows.forEach(data =>
        this.store.dispatch(
          new ActionOutbankImportAdd({ transaction: data })
        )
      );
    });
```

the ActionOutbankImportAdd Actions are triggered but the newly dispatched ActionOutbankImportSuccess | ActionOutbankImportError which i use for progress calculation is only called once at the end.

Whats the best practice for handling such a big import process together with progress indication ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: tldr: This comment does not answer the question, it's just my oppinion. My personal oppinion is that "import processes" should be handled on the backend. If progress should be visiblie to the user, websockets or similar technologies could communicate to the browser. Having the import in the browser is brittle and probably also a huge load on the client system as well as the network.

Comment: This is a good hint. Due the lack of time i use a mongo db with loopback api on top,  so i have to  create an extra web service which accepts the file and imports it. But you're totally right  this would be the cleanest solution. My hope was to manage it this way so I don't have to write  some extra services. Anyway, if someone has a solution it would be great to share it ;)